# Left Join in Subsonic 3

Tags: linq, subsonic3, left-join

I'm trying to do a left join in subsonic 3 using linq but it doesn't seem to work, I get a big error.

```
        var post = from p in Post.All()
                    join q in Quote.All() on p.ID equals q.PostID into pq
                    where p.ID == id.Value
                    from qt in pq.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new {p, qt};
```

I'm using subsonic 3, latest GIT version from Rob, but I'm getting an error, see below, when I try a left join.
I have searched but I didn't found any solution.

Can anyone explain to me why the error and how to fix it?
Thanks

`Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[GetAQuote.Post]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[GetAQuote.Post]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[<>f__AnonymousType221[GetAQuote.Post], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1%5BGetAQuote.Quote%5D, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func2%5BGetAQuote.Post,System.Int32%5D%5D, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func2%5BGetAQuote.Quote,System.Int32%5D%5D, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func3%5BGetAQuote.Post,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[GetAQuote.Quote],<>f__AnonymousType22%5BGetAQuote.Post,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1%5BGetAQuote.Quote%5D%5D%5D%5D">GetAQuote.Post,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[GetAQuote.Quote]]] GroupJoin[Post,Quote,Int32,<>f__AnonymousType22'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve Left Join in Subsonic3 you just need to set .AsEnumerable() method on your linq query.

Try this

categories.AsEnumerable() or products.AsEnumerable()

Comment: When I tried this, I got past the error, but the resulting database activity was a select all from both tables, apparently leaving all the joining logic to be done in core.  That's not right, is it?

Comment: @Kelly, I've been looking into the core of Subsonic 3 and yes this does appear to be what is happening. `.AsEnumerable` is apparently equivalent to `.ToList` in that it gets absolutely everything from the database. Further more, there does not appear to be any code in Subsonic to handle nested queries